# niveles de usuario login

Tags: php, pdo, login

He creado un código que diferencia niveles de usuario, en concreto 2, cliente y administrador a la hora de loguearse empleando PDO.

La cosa es que es que inicialmente puse en la página de cliente este código

**cliente.php**

```
<BODY>

    <!--    NIVEL USUARIO    -->
    <?PHP
    /*
    En este código comprobamos el nivel de privilegio del usuario logueado
        1 -> Super usuario
        2 -> Usuario plano
    En función de este redirigimos a una página u otra.
    */
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
            if($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1){
                header("location:admin.php");
            }
        }else{
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    ?>
    <!------------------------->

    <h1> <strong>Bienvenido </strong><?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["nombre"]; ?></h1>
    <p> Panel de control | <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] ==1? 'Admin' : 'Cliente'; ?></p>
</body>
```

Y en la del administrador este otro código muy parecido

**admin.php**

```
<?PHP
    /*
    En este código comprobamos el nivel de privilegio del usuario logueado
        1 -> Super usuario
        2 -> Usuario plano
    En función de este redirigimos a una página u otra.
    */
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
            if($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 2){
                header("location:cliente.php");
            }
        }else{
            header("location:index.php");   
        }
    ?>
    <!------------------------->

    <h1> <strong>Bienvenido </strong><?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["nombre"]; ?></h1>
    <p> Panel de control | <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] ==1? 'Admin' : 'Cliente'; ?></p>
```

Hasta aquí iba genial, porque conseguía que si alguien cambia la url de manera manual, el código comprueba dicho nivel y no te permite pasar al otro nivel de usuario.

El problema es cuando he querido simplificar mi código, ya que al ser tan parecido pensé en crear un fichero php aparte y llamarlo en ambos ficheros, admin.php y cliente.php

Hice lo siguiente

**nivelUsuario.php**

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){
    if($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1){
        header("location:admin.php");
    } else {
        header("location:cliente.php");
    }
}else{
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

Y en admin.php y cliente.php lo llamo con un include.

```
<BODY>

    <!--    NIVEL USUARIO    -->
    <?PHP
        session_start();
        include 'PHP/LogIn/nivelUsuario.php';
    ?>
    <!------------------------->

    <h1> <strong>Bienvenido </strong> <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["nombre"]; ?></h1>
    <p> Panel de control | <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] ==1? 'Admin' : 'Cliente'; ?></p>
```

El problema ahora es que SIEMPRE salta a la página del admin.php y además ya no hay seguridad, si yo en la url pongo https//:blabla/admin.php o https//:blabla/cliente.php, no hay seguridad alguna, va directo a esa página sin importar nada.

Otro error que me sale es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que se ve, el problema es que tu pagina la cual redirige, al estar presente en todas las opciones, siempre va a estar redirigiendo, por ende el error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` osea queda en un bucle eterno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero**: Tanto en `admin.php` como en `cliente.php` estás incluyendo el script de redirección:

```
include 'PHP/LogIn/nivelUsuario.php
```

Luego pensemos que un admin se loguea y entra a `admin.php`. Si está logueado se cumple que

```
$_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1
```

Y el script lo redirige a `admin.php`, que a su vez incluye el script de redirección, y **eso ocurre en un loop infinito**.

(salvo para el usuario que no está logueado y llega a `index.php`, suponiendo que ese script no incluye al script de redirección)

**Edit: (se me olvidó sugerir la solución!)**

Tu script de redirección debiera comprobar si, dado el privilegio del usuario, éste debiera ser redirigido o se encuentra ya en la página que le corresponde y en ese caso no redirigirlo:

```
<?php

session_start();

$script_actual = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) && $script_actual !== 'index.php') {

  header("Location: index.php");

} else if($_SESSION["usuario"]["privilegio"] == 1 && $script_actual !== 'admin.php') {

  header("Location: admin.php");

} else if ($script_actual !== 'cliente.php') {

  header("Location: cliente.php");

}
```

**Nota:** 
El uso de la llave `SCRIPT_NAME` en la superglobal `$_SERVER` me funciona usando nginx+fastcgi, pero el contenido de las llaves no siempre se comporta igual (a lo mejor en Apache esa llave no estará poblada).

Ya no me acuerdo exactamente cuál llave es universal, pero si no te funciona, debieras probar también `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']`. Recuerda envolver ese valor en `basename(<valor>)` para que no te entregue la ruta completa sino sólo el nombre del script que se ha llamado.

---

**En segundo lugar**, estás llamando dos veces a `session_start()`. Esto genera un error de tipo `E_NOTICE` que probablemente no ves porque tienes deshabilitado `display_errors` o bien tu nivel de error excluye ese tipo de errores que usualmente se consideran irrelevantes.

**Por último:** Cuando escribes:

```
<body>
<?php
header('Location: cliente.php`);
```

El sólo hecho de escribir `<body>` ya envía contenido al browser, para lo cual envía los headers respectivos, luego el header de redirección debiera tirar otro error. `Headers already sent`.

Lo correcto sería incluir ese script antes del html:

```
<?php
include('redireccion.php`);

?> 
<html>
  <body>
   ...
  <body>
</html>
```